# PHP - I'm a little confused on $_POST and in_array

Tags: php

Alright so i receive from $_POST and i need my code do something like this

```
if ($_POST contains EU-London) {
//do stuff here
}else{
//failed to find EU-London
}
```

Now i've been told several ways to find a certain phrase in code but the posted data contains:

```
 Array
 (
     [EU-London] => 
 )
```

How would i check if the EU-London is there? because pregmatch uses strings and im not sure how to grab this using in_array()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a **key** in `$_POST`:

```
if (isset($_POST['EU-London'])) {
  // Key exists.
}
```

As correctly commented by Robert, the proper way to check for an existing key would be

```
if (array_key_exists('EU-London', $_POST)) {
  // Key exists.
}
```

Comment: actually the proper way to check if key exists is function` array_key_exists()` isset check if key exists and is set but you can have 'key' = null and isset will return false

Comment: Thank you so much! i can't believe it was that simple! I feel pretty stupid i get confused when it comes to using $_POST

Comment: @Robert True, but we talking about POST data, this corner case is very unlikely. Will update my answer though.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if isset key

```
if (isset($_POST['EU-London'])) {
    //key isset
}
```